# What is the best way to develop *.js with ServiceStack self-host?

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-razor

Due "Copy to Output" for js files it is impossible to just edit js file and reload the page to see the changes. It is required to restart the service.

One of the possible solutions is to modify VFS to look at js files in the correct location (solution tree, not in the output folder) in DEBUG mode.

Any other suggestions?

Thanks,
Dmitry

Comment: I think the option you specified is the only practical one.  I assume you're developing JS using some modern tool (from vi to Visual Studio) and saving it to the disk.  You're basically asking for ServiceStack to load a file from the file system each time it is requested by a service, as opposed to the copy placed in your \bin directory.  The VFS is designed to do just that.

Comment: I tried the solution like so: `WebHostPhysicalPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` but it didnt work, any ideas?

Comment: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory points to the directory where your *.exe is located, it is "Output path" in terms of VS. But you need to point WebHostPhysicalPath to the directory with your markup. Usually it is a directory with your *.csproj

Comment: Yeah I tried that too but no luck, still have to restart the whole service to see any changes. Also, what is VFS?

Comment: Just double check your paths, it should works. About VFS - ServiceStack have abstraction over file system (https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Virtual-file-system), it is possible to change default VFS implementation to new one which will load content files (*.js and so on) from the correct folder.

Comment: Ah right, thanks for your help, I'll keep playing with it to see if I can get it to work, now that I know it should be possible! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig
{
    WebHostPhysicalPath = "C:\\projects\\path_to_self_host_project"
});
```